# App crashes in AppDelegate and cannot get past launch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

The app crashes in AppDelegate, unable to get beyond the launch screen. No view controller code ever gets executed.

The stack trace is also not very helpful nor is the line highlighted in AppDelegate when the crash occurs.

Images below provide the details.

How to debug from here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You say: "The stack trace is also not very helpful..." What is the actual stack trace?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: @Gordonium sorry the stack trace (as shown by the illustration) ... no view controller code gets executed so wondering how to proceed. as you can see in the first screenshot, the app crashes on the class declaration line in `appdelegate` without further explanation.

Comment: Is `@UIApplicationMain` or the function `UIApplicationMain` any where else in your project?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint.  Something is probably nil and you force unwrapped it

Comment: @Paulw11 ok thanks will try that.

Comment: @Paulw11 the exception breakpoint stops on the same line as shown in the first screenshot (AppDelegate). Other suggestions?

Comment: @dan thanks for the article, but all the steps were tried including adding an exception breakpoint as paulw11 suggested. the question isn't how to debug crashes in general but how to debug this specific one that offers such little information to begin with.

Comment: What happens when you press the debugger continue button |> ?  You need to get a real exception message.  Has this app ever worked?  What did you change?

Comment: Yes the app worked previously. Only changed a few things in Main.Storyboard but cannot revert back unfortunately. Pressing the continue button just shows assembly code. There is no exception message that appears, that's the frustrating part. @Paulw11

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding everything.

Comment: @ryantxr tried several times to no avail. any other suggestions?

Comment: Check any IBOutlet links carefully; you may have deleted the property from your view controller but the UI element is still connected to it.  It is always a good idea to use version control; Xcode can create a local git repository if you don't want to use an external provider, that way you can roll back to known working versions

Comment: I sure would like to see the stack trace.

Comment: @Paulw11 great idea on the outlets! yes, we do have version control but didn't check this last batch because they were *supposed* to be minor.

Comment: @Paulw11 wow that was frustrating! can you please post the outlet suggestion. that was the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check any IBOutlet links carefully; you may have deleted the property from your view controller but the UI element is still connected to it.  This should give you an exception stating something like *Class ViewController is not key value coding-compliant for key XXX* where XXX is your bad IBOutlet, however Swift's exception reporting does seem to be a bit hit-and-miss at times.

Comment: Yes, typically Xcode gives the `Class ViewController is not key value coding-compliant for key XXX` error, but it didn't for some reason this time. So frustrating, but thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible cause related to the reason Paulw11 stated that may help someone else.

If you have segue's in your storyboard that links to a storyboard reference in another bundle, and you change the name of the bundle where the reference resides, make sure to update the Bundle name in your storyboard for the linked reference.

I have a framework I'm developing that contains some storyboards and UI components. I decided to rename the framework, updated the podfile references in the app and all the file imports to reflect the new framework name but completely forgot that there were storyboard references in the app referencing view controllers provided in storyboards in the framework.

Here's an example:
[image: Storyboard screenshot]

If you do not rename the reference you will experience a crash when you try to load the storyboard containing your link with no hint as to why. I spent an embarrassing amount of time hunting this down.